# SQLDataadapter with Delete

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am just using select query and filling the dataset. and do some changes and I want to delete this entry in the dataset I am doing this

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dsDatadata.Tables[0].Rows)
                                {
                                    dr.Delete();
                                }



                                sdAdapter.Update(dsDatadata,"DataData");
```

But it is not working .

Note:- I dont want to use SQL Delete command

How to resolve this?

Comment: You should give more detail... how is it not working ? do you get an exception ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `sdAdapter` doesn't have a `Command` for the SQL Delete Command.
You can auto-generate the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands for the adapter by using a `CommandBuilder`, but it only works for simple queries (for single-table, no join).

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsDatadata.Tables[0].Rows) {
  dr.Delete();
}
DataAdapter sdAdapter;

DbCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sdAdapter);
sdAdapter.Update(dsDatadata, "DataData");
```

Note: I used the SQLCommandBuilder but you should replace it with the one you use (OleDB...)
See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) for more details...

If your query is more complicated, then there is no easy path, you'll have to write the SQL yourself.